# Why didn't the Communist Party in Czechoslovakia use the military to suppress the protests during the Velvet Revolution?

Tags: 20th-century, communism, czechoslovakia

I've been reading a bit about the fairly peaceful transition of power in Czechoslovokia through the protests throughout the country, but I'm wondering, why didn't the ruling party attempt to bring the military to the streets to shut down the protesters with force?

Comment: Likely for fear that the military wouldn't follow orders.  This was not an [unfounded belief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_Revolution#Military_defection_and_Ceau.C8.99escu.27s_fall)

Comment: I believe this was tried (unsuccessfully) during the Hungarian Revolution of 1956,.

Comment: The regime would colapse sooner or later with everyone on the democratic side.

Answer (score 8):

Communism has always been buttressed by force.

In Eastern Europe it was either actual Soviet troops ([Germany-1953](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uprising_of_1953_in_East_Germany), [Hungary-1956](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_Revolution_of_1956), [Czechoslovakia-1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Pact_invasion_of_Czechoslovakia)) or the imminent credible threat thereof ([Poland-1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martial_law_in_Poland)). Local troops has never been [particularly reliable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_Revolution#Military_defection_and_Ceau.C8.99escu.27s_fall).

You need to look at the [**context**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_of_1989). Communism was crumbling **everywhere**. By 1989, Gorbachev made it clear that USSR will not intervene, and it was perfectly clear that the communist power could not be kept.
The choice was not "keep power by force" vs "relinquish power" but "relinquish power peacefully" or "be forced out".

Comment: It seems like the actual choice was between "go peacefully" or "be shot".

Comment: @jamesqf: yes, this is how it did pan out at the end.